# is there a way I can recycle elements of the shorter list in purrr:: map2 or purrr::walk2?

Tags: r, purrr

`purrr` does not seem to support recycling of elements of a vector in case there is a shortage of elements in one of the two (while using `purrr::map2` or `purrr::walk2`). Unlike baseR where we just get a warning if the larger vector is not a multiple of the shorter one.

Consider this toy example:

This works:

```
map2(1:3,4:6,sum)
#

#[[1]]
#[1] 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 7

#[[3]]
#[1] 9
```

And this doesn't work:

```
map2(1:3,4:9,sum)
```

> Error: `.x` (3) and `.y` (6) are different lengths

I understand very well why this is not allowed - as it can make catching bugs very difficult. But is there any way in purrr I can force this to happen? Perhaps using some base R trick with purrr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put both lists in a data frame and let that command repeat your vectors:

```
input <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:9)
purrr::map2(input$a, input$b, sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's by design with *`purrr`* but you can use `Map` :

```
Map(sum,1:3,4:9)
# [[1]]
# [1] 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 7
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 9
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 8
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 10
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 12
```

And here's how I would recycle if I had to :

```
x <- 1:3
y <- 4:9
l <- max(length(y), length(x))
map2(rep(x,len = l), rep(y,len = l),sum)
# [[1]]
# [1] 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 7
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 9
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 8
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 10
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 12
```

Comment: I guess I prefer the solution given by A.stam (i.e. Transferring the vectors into data.frame variables) as it is shorter & elegant.

Comment: Consider giving him the green tick mark if his solution solved your case.